# Get the path of an uploaded image and store it into database and access it later for diaplaying the image?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the current path of the image that was uploaded into a folder an atorw that path into the database e.g

nweb/images//uploads/

I want to get the above mentioned path in php and store it in database and later retrieve it from database and diaplay the image.

My db structure e.g

id, imageName, imagePath

Answer (score 0):

1. I think rest of the file path is same, except the file name.
2. You can save the file name instead of the whole path in the data base,When you upload the file.
3. Then in the reference point (image displaying place), you can hard code the image path except file name.
4. You can search for the specific file name in the database and place it there.

Hope you are expecting this kind of an answer. If it is not please comment on this, I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can move your uploaded file using the [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) function. Eg:

```
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
```

Here the second argument is the destination. You can set it yourself. You just have to insert it into the database for retrieving the file later.